# Unsafe sun class implementation

Tags: java, virtual-machine

```
/**
     * Atomically update Java variable to <tt>x</tt> if it is currently
     * holding <tt>expected</tt>.
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if successful
     */
    public final native boolean compareAndSwapObject(Object o, long offset,
                                                     Object expected,
                                                     Object x);
```

1) How do they "atomically" set the value of "o" at position "offset" to "x" if "value==expected"?

2) How do they "lock" the object when we use synchronized method or synchronized block? I am just curious to know what goes under the hood.

Comment: I think you are going to need a textbook.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Can you give me the/any textbook name?

Comment: Actually, I doubt that there's a textbook that covers the topic accurately/deeply.  It's the sort of thing you pick up on the street.

Comment: The whole point of this operation is that it is lock less, the guarantee of thread safety is provided by the CPU hardware.

Comment: If you are curious enough, you can download the OpenJDK source code and see how it is done.

Comment: @StephenC: Actually, the code I mentioned above is from jarvana. There is no implementation in that method. I also tried looking at the openJDK source from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java That also has the same signature, implementation is not shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As this is native method,  they will fall back to whatever is offered by target platform.  IIRC, "compare and swap"  was present on MIPS and SPARC  as processor command more than 10 years ago.
2. they use something like 1 behind the scenes to obtain lock on object

Answer (score 2):

Yep, the `compareAndSwapObject` call translates into either a native method call or an inline expansion that does the compare-and-swap using native hardware facilities.

As to implementation of the `synchronized` keyword, any number of techniques may be used, but they all resemble the compare-and-swap conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to your question is implementation dependent.

See here for the atomic package docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

The implementation usually utilized machine-level atomic instructions like compare and swap.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take a look at what Intel offers for their x86 processors family.

[Implementing scalable atomic locks for multi core intel em64t and ia32 architectures.](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures/)